# The Authorize(Roles="") tag and IIS 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-6, windows-authentication, windows-server-2003

I have some problems when I deploy my website on IIS 6. I am on a intranet and I have set the security to Windows authentication, without the Authorize(Roles="") tag my site work and it display my active directory user name in the welcome message (website on IIS 6). With the Authorize(Roles="") tag, it works when lauched from visual studio on IIS express. But with the tag and the site on IIS 6, when I browse to the site I get the login prompt and no credentials work. Does anyone have an idea of something I might have missed or something I simply don't know yet. Any help will be very appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that you are typing domain\username? It's a common thing when authenticating that people attempt to authenticate as their domain/pc name instead of the target domain/pc name.

Regards

Liam

Comment: yeah I think I did it right, the tag looks like this
[Authorize(Roles=@"DOMAIN\UserGroup")]
it is working on IIS Express as I expected, and the authentication itself seems to work on IIS 6 since without the tag it logs me in and display my user name..